# Wix Managed Bootstrapper Application: When do the Detect* events fire?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

As soon as my Wix MBA starts up (actually in the main view's codebehind constructor), I set event handlers for a bunch of Detect* events in the BA:

```
LogDetect("Setting bootstrapper detection handlers");
bootstrapperApplication.DetectRelatedBundle += BootstrapperOnDetectRelatedBundle;
bootstrapperApplication.DetectPackageComplete += BootstrapperApplicationOnDetectPackageComplete;
bootstrapperApplication.DetectRelatedMsiPackage += BootstrapperOnDetectRelatedMsiPackage;
bootstrapperApplication.DetectPriorBundle += BootstrapperOnDetectPriorBundle;
bootstrapperApplication.DetectMsiFeature += BootstrapperApplicationOnDetectMsiFeature;
bootstrapperApplication.DetectComplete += BootstrapperApplicationOnDetectComplete;
bootstrapperApplication.DetectBegin += BootstrapperApplicationOnDetectBegin;
```

then I make the call to Detect():

```
LogDetect("Beginning detection of existing installations...");
bootstrapperApplication.Engine.Detect();
```

Inside of these handlers I only make calls to `LogDetect()`. I know that `LogDetect()` works because those two calls I have outside of the handlers do log the messages, however no other messages are logged by `LogDetect()` which means the handlers are never called.

I figured at least `DetectBegin` and `DetectComplete` would fire.

I thought the events would be fired shortly after I make the call to `Detect()`. When does it actually happen?

**Edit:** If I look in the logfile in the user's temp directory it does show that Detect is happening. Those log entries are not mine (they are marked iXXX where the i stands for internal I presume).

---

(Sidenote: there's this somewhat related question, the fact that it hasn't been answered is not very promising... [Wix Bootstrapper: Sequence of Bootstrapper events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018262/wix-bootstrapper-sequence-of-bootstrapper-events))

Comment: Does the install log in the user's temp directory show that the Detect action is happening?  What exactly do you mean by "As soon as my Wix MBA starts up"?  Your BootstrapperApplication's constructor?  Its Run method?

Comment: @SeanHall I updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they were firing all along; they were simply trying to do work on a different thread :/